# CLI MAMP PHP running slowly compared to OS X PHP

Tags: php, command-line-interface, mamp

Ive just started to encounter a problem with MAMP PHP running extremely slowly. Ive reinstalled MAMP and still having issues.

As a comparison (I thought maybe my local development OS X machine may have been having issues) i tried the following in terminal, and disabled php.ini with `-n`

```
/usr/bin/php --version -n
```

This returns with an output immediately.

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin/php --version -n
```

This returns an output approx 3-5 seconds later.

I have tried running numerous other commands and scripts. All seem to have a delay of 3-5 seconds with MAMP PHP.

I have tried other MAMP PHP versions, and they still have the same issues.

I can't think of anything that has changed recently on my machine to cause this slow down (e..g no php.ini changes, no OS X updates)

I really have no idea whats causing this problem, or even how to investigate things further. Help greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Strangely, the problem only seems to be when running MAMP PHP in command line. When loading a website using MAMP, there is no slow down. Even more confusing...

Comment: Wrong place to ask this question. Have a try over at the ServerFault sister page.

Comment: I disagree - "Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow." - this is about my development environment, so surely belongs here?

Comment: Ah, sorry, usually a LAMP stack (or similar) is used to create business related solutions. Keep in mind that business does not mean commercial. It certainly is your decision. I just thought you will get faster and better replies over there.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll keep it here as Server Fault relates more to production servers. Im talking about my development laptop running MAMP. The slow down is driving me nuts!

Comment: @arkascha: Products namend MAMP/XAMPP etc. are dev tools, as opposed to the standard LAMP stack, and they are actually off-topic on SF.

Comment: @arkascha MAMP is a "tool primarily used for programming" and as such questions about it really don't belong on [sf].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved. For some reason `-n` was not removing the .ini files. Deleting the .ini file altogether solved the issue.

Some googling lead me to the extension causing the issue. I commented out the following line in my .ini file

```
; extension=imap.so
```

Comment: me too. After comment imap.so, problem solved. But I don't know why. Is there any clue?

Comment: yes, its trying to do a DNS lookup for the local hostname. Adding the relevant entries to your /etc/hosts file resolves the problem without disabling the module.

Answer (score 20):

As indicated by the other replies, the slow-down is caused by the imap.so extension.

Looking deeper into this though, it appears that the reason why is that it's trying perform a DNS lookup for the local machine's hostname.

Adding your hostname to your /etc/hosts file should fix it:

```
me@mbp ~> hostname 
mbp.local

cat /etc/hosts
...
127.0.0.1     mbp.local
::1           mbp.local
...
```

Before:

```
me@mbp ~> time php -v
PHP 7.0.12 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2016 18:49:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
        **5.04 real**         0.01 user         0.01 sys
```

After:

```
me@mbp ~> time php -v
PHP 7.0.12 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2016 18:49:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
        **0.03 real**         0.01 user         0.00 sys
```

I discovered this by capturing the network traffic using Wireshark.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. What exactly are you adding? Should the 'hostname' be an actual hostname. What is the 'me@mbp' part and where do I find the equivalent of this? I don't understand which bits of this code should be cut and pasted into the hosts file and which are specific? I'm new to MAMP etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having this problem too on MAMP 6.5 where it always takes 5 seconds to load a page with images on. Incredibly annoying. My Mac won't let me amend the hosts file either.